# Monotouch - Can't dismiss current view on button click

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have a view where I'm letting a user edit a `EntryElement`. I register the click event fine through the delegate of the "Done" button however, I can't get it to dismiss the current view to go to the previous view though. Here's what I'm trying right now:

```
AppDelegate.navigation.PresentedViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

I've also tried:

```
AppDelegate.navigation.PresentedViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
```

`navigation` is just a `UINavigationController`

EDIT:

I am using `Monotouch.Dialog` to build out all of the views. This view is created via a method. I want it to go back to the previous view once they click the done button. Here's the contents of the method:

```
public static void EditClientTypeView (string typeName, string typeId)
        {
            DialogViewController editClientTypeVC;
            UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done);

            EntryElement element = new EntryElement("Type Name", "Name of client type", typeName, false);

            var root = new RootElement ("Edit Type") {
                new Section () {
                    element
                }
            };

            editClientTypeVC = new DialogViewController (root, true);
            editClientTypeVC.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = doneButton;

            doneButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
                // Need to save the edited client type to the database
                Console.WriteLine("Done button clicked signifying the user is finished editing");
                AppDelegate.navigation.PresentedViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
                //AppDelegate.navigation.DismissViewController(true, null);
            };

            AppDelegate.navigation.PushViewController(editClientTypeVC, true);
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you displaying the view you want to dismiss?

Comment: Edited my question with the method I'm using to create the view and handle the click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are PUSHING a view controller onto the Navigation Stack, you dismiss it by POPPING it off the stack.  [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has three POP methods

- PopToRootViewController - goes all the way back to the root view of your navigation controller
- PopToViewController - pops back to a specific view controller
- PopViewController - pops back to the "previous" view controller

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! I used `PopViewControllerAnimated(true)` to pop back to my previous controller.